# IPhone App Provisioning Account For Multiple Developers

Tags: iphone, ipad, deployment, provisioning

Ive only previously been developing the Apps for our company by myself and Provision management has been quite simple. We have now added another developer to the project and i am having trouble setting up the provisioning for both of us to deploy and test to out iphone.

Does anybody know if there is a step by step or any tips on how to set up provisioning for a multi developer scenario project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are having trouble sending the iphone developer certificate, if you want to share it, you have to share the private key of the certificate. Not only the public part which can be downloaded from the member center. For that, you have to get into the KeyChain, look for the developer certificate, expand it and right click over the key, then export the key and send it to the new developer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Will the Export Developer Profile button in Organizer do this for me?

Comment: Im not sure, i haven't tried that before, but im sure the way I told you before will work properly

Answer (score 0):

We use a team provisioning profile that was created and managed by xcode. If we get a new developer they just login to the dev portal in organiser and then they can deploy. Unfortunately I can't remember how I did it because it was like two small things and it just worked.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to:

- Export your Developer Cert from your
  KeyChain and send it to your second
  developer
- Export your Distribution Cert from
  your key chain and send it (if you want him to be able to submit to the app store or send out ad-hoc builds to beta testers)
- Go to your Provisioning Portal and
  add his device to your portal
- Then go hit edit on all your
  provisioning profiles, adding his
  device to each of them
- You will both need to download the
  new versions of your provisioning
  profiles

(Adding his device to the portal & downloading new profiles can be done through the xcode organiser, its usually faster that way)